# ServletTest configuration setResourceBase to locate JSP

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I have a servlet which do a `getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp") .forward(request, response)`
 and Jetty is not locating the `index.jsp` file. 
I have set the "setResourceBase" to the location of the jsp, but it does not works. 
Anyone figure the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you set

```
context.setServingResources(true);
```

Comment: i do not have this method. I can get the context object by calling getContext(), but this context object does not have an setServingResources.

Comment: Can you include the jetty version in your OP